# How to determine if Outlook has any contacts

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

I have a VB.NET windows application in which I'm using Outlook's contacts as my address book to get a list of email addresses. I'd like it to use Outlook as the address book, but if an Outlook mailbox has not been set up or there are no contacts then I don't want Outlook to come up at all. The problem that I'm having is as soon as I try to access Outlook the Outlook Startup Wizard comes up, which I don't want to happen. Here is my code:

```
Dim ao As Outlook.Application
Dim ons As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Contacts As Outlook.Items

ao = New Outlook.Application
' The Outlook Startup Wizard comes up on this line of code.
ons = ao.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Comment: @Luiscencio - Think his post could entail C# OR VB.NET as its all the same CLR.  He's looking for any solution and could even take a C# solution and convert.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following registry key to see if Outlook has been configured yet:

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Messaging Subsystem\Profiles"

The following code sample demonstrates this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Outlook Profile Setup?:" + OutlookProfileExists().ToString())

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function OutlookProfileExists() As Boolean
        Dim rk As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser
        Dim sk = rk.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles")

        Return sk.SubKeyCount > 0
    End Function
End Module
```

Assuming it's configured then launch like normal and check the contact list.  I can't find anyway to read the contact list without launching it, but at least you can verify if it's configured.