# how to check if user has MS outlook installed before launching a calendar sync using devexpress xtrascheduler

Tags: devexpress

I have an application that uses the DevExpress XtraScheduler technology, that onLoad does a synchronization with the application calendar and my local MS outlook on my desktop. The application works great however I was wondering if a user DOES NOT have MS outlook on their machines and the application loads for the first time on that specific user's desktop  that doesn’t have MS outlook a few nasty errors could (or should) occur I would imagine.

In your opinion how could one a actually provide a check or error handling to cater for a scenario like this - informing the user that no MS outlook has been detected?

Thank you in advance and kind regards
geoNeo

PS- I am using VS 2010, programming in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page of the documentation.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3937

In particular, the `OutlookExchangeHelper` class should give you everything you need.

Comment: hi there Kuffs thank you for the the tip - however I cam across the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283982/how-to-determine-if-outlook-has-any-contacts, and it seems this will work for my purposes at the moment. I did check with Devexpress as well and it seems that it is suitable for the current implementation. Thanks again for your reply. kind regards geoNeo

Comment: that would work but is unnecessary as Devexpress already provide you with the tools you need (in one line of code) without resorting to hacks.

Comment: i did think so too - but like said asked devexpress and they provided me with this nugget. I do agree with you though, thanks again. :D

Answer (score 0):

here is some code that will do two things:
1) Check if it's installed
2) Get the version number that's installed

Hope this helps

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Module Outlook


    Public Class Outlook
        Public Shared Function isInstalled() As Boolean
            Dim regClasses As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot
            Dim rtn As Boolean

            Dim reg As RegistryKey = regClasses.OpenSubKey("Outlook.Application")
            If reg Is Nothing Then
                rtn = False
            Else
                rtn = True
            End If
            reg.Close()

            Return rtn
        End Function

        Public Shared Function version() As String
            Dim rtn As String = ""
            Dim objApp As Object

            If isInstalled() Then
                objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                rtn = objApp.Version
            End If

            Return rtn
        End Function
    End Class
End Module
```